# Let $(a_n) \subset \mathbb R^+$ an increasing sequence and $(b_n) \subset \mathbb R^+$ not bounded, such that $a_n \geq nb_n \forall n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to prove or disprove if the sequence $(a_{n+1} - a_n)$ is bounded

The idea of the statement is that the distance between consecutive $a_n$ terms keep increasing, without a bound.

Since $a_n \geq nb_n \forall n \in \mathbb N$, $a_n$ is not bounded too ($a_n \geq nb_n \geq b_n \gt \epsilon $), but I couldn't do anything else. Also, I couldn't see why $a_n \geq nb_n$ would be necessary instead of $a_n \geq b_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $(a_{n + 1} - a_n)$ is bounded, i.e. there exists $A > 0$ such that $a_{n + 1} - a_n \leq A$ for all $n$.

It is then easy to prove by induction that $a_n \leq nA + a_0$. Thus $a_n \leq  n(A + a_0)$ for all $n \geq 1$.

This leads to $b_n \leq \frac 1 n a_n \leq A + a_0$ for all $n \geq 1$. But $(b_n)$ is by assumption unbounded, a contradiction.

Therefore $(a_{n + 1} - a_n)$ must be unbounded.

To see that the weaker assumption $a_n \geq b_n$ does not suffices, just look at the example $a_n = b_n = n$.